# Find 2nd generation Cloud Function logs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-logging

To find logging from my 1st generation Cloud Function (called backup-tableau) I use the following query in Cloud Logging:

```
resource.type="cloud_function"
resource.labels.function_name="backup-tableau"
```

But I switched now to a 2nd generation Cloud Function and cannot find my logs.
How can I find that function in my logs?

Comment: I answered my own question, but if there's better answers, I really like to know them :)

Answer (score 3):

2nd generation Cloud Functions use Cloud Run, so you use the following query:

```
resource.type="cloud_run_revision" OR resource.type="cloud_function"
resource.labels.service_name="backup-tableau" OR resource.labels.function_name="backup-tableau"
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @Sander van den Oord, you can use the query he shows.  The shortcut to the query is under the Cloud Function's LOGS tab.  It will open essentially the same query.

```
(resource.type = "cloud_function"
resource.labels.function_name = "your-function"
resource.labels.region = "your-region")
 OR 
(resource.type = "cloud_run_revision"
resource.labels.service_name = "your-function"
resource.labels.location = "your-region")
 severity>=DEFAULT
```

[image]